Potential energy of an electric dipole
I've read in my book and on wikipedia that given an electric dipole with dipole moment $\mathbf{p}$ immersed in an electric field $\mathbf{E}$, its potential energy is
$$U_e = -\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{E}$$
The derivation of this formula used the fact that given a particular rotation of the dipole the electric field applied a torque as to rotate it until the electric dipole is aligned in the direction of $\mathbf{E}$.
I then solved an exercise in which there were two electric dipoles with moments $\mathbf{p}_1$ and $\mathbf{p}_2$ which were parallel, and it asked me to compute the potential energy.
The book also showed that, if a non uniform electric field is only applied on one axis $x$, the intensity of force applied on a dipole by the field is
$$F = p \frac{dE}{dx}$$
To solve the problem I then tried to use the definition of potential energy and considered the field created by the first dipole at a distance $r$ on the same axis as the dipole itself, which is given by
$$E_1 (x) =  \frac{p_1}{2 \pi \varepsilon_0 r^3}$$


I then imagined taking the second dipole from a distance of infinity to a distance of $x$, so in order to find the intensity of the force I calculated the derivative
$$\frac{dE}{dr} = \frac{p_1}{2 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{-3}{r^4}$$
The force applied on the second dipole over a distance $r$ must then be
$$\mathbf{F} = p_2 \frac{dE}{dr} \hat{\mathbf{r}} = \frac{p_2 p_1}{2 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{-3}{r^4} \hat{\mathbf{r}}$$
Finding the work I then got
$$W = \int_{\infty}^x \frac{p_1 p_2}{2 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{-3}{r^4} dr = \frac{p_1 p_2}{2 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{1}{x^3} = - U_e$$
This gets us
$$U_e = - \frac{p_1 p_2}{2 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{1}{x^3}$$
However, using the original formula, I got the same thing
$$U_e = -\mathbf{p}_2 \cdot \mathbf{E_1} (r=x) = -p_2 E_1 (r=x) = - \frac{p_2 p_1}{2 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{1}{x^3}$$
So my question is, if one form of energy was derived with respect to the rotation, whilst here we I derived the same thing with respect to the position, is it a coincidence that these two energies are the same in this case? Or does this mean that $U_e = - \mathbf{p \cdot E}$ is always valid? My understanding was that potential energy is energy "stored" in the state of an object, as in its position or rotation, so is it a case that the energy "stored" due to its rotation is the same as the energy "stored" due to its position? Or am I getting this wrong and somehow thesetwo represent the same exact energy? If so why can it be derived in both ways which apparently seem to take a completely different approach, one finding the energy stored in rotation and the other in the position?

i think this happens because as you take it from infinity to the point x you increase its potential energy which is stored in by rotating the dipole from the angle theta such that the repulsions minimize.
